# Sub-setting data table using & and grepl

Tags: r, data.table, subset, grepl

I've got a data set with column names like:

```
names(d)
 [1] "Code"        "LX(RI)"      "LX(VO)"      "LX(MV)"      "LX(WC189)" "LX(WC035)"
 [7] "NX(RI)"      "NX(VO)"      "NX(MV)"      "NX(WC189)"   "NX(WC035)" "AX(RI)"     
[13] "AX(VO)"      "AX(MV)"      "AX(WC189)"   "AX(WC035)"   "SX3I(RI)"  "SXI(VO)"    
[19] "SXI(MV)"     "TX(RI)"      "TX(VO)"      "TX(MV)"      "TX(WC189)" "TX(WC035)"
```

Each column has several thousand rows associated with it. What I want to do is use `grepl` to subset the data table's columns based on those ending with RI AND retaining the Code column.

Currently I've worked out how to subset all the RI columns into a new data.table, but I can't figure out how to include the Code column.

I have currently:

```
RI <- d[, grepl("\\(RI", names(d)), with = FALSE]
```

Which gives me what I want:

```
names(RI)
[1] "LX(RI)" "NX(RI)" "AX(RI)" "SX3I(RI)" "TX(RI)"
```

I've been trying (note that I have included &Code):

```
RI <- d[, grepl("\\(RI&Code", names(d)), with = FALSE]
```

Which I want to return a data table with the following columns:

```
[1] "LX(RI)" "NX(RI)" "AX(RI)" "SX3I(RI)" "TX(RI)" "Code"
```

The above is my desired output. The code however does nothing and returns an empty data table.

A couple of questions:

- Can I use & in grepl? If so, is my example using & incorrect?
- If not, are there any suggestions on how to subset for both RI columns and the Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ab <- c("Code","LX(RI)","LX(VO)","LX(MV)","TX(RI)","NX(RI)","NX(RI)")


ab[grepl("Code|RI",ab)]

[1] "Code"   "LX(RI)" "TX(RI)" "NX(RI)" "NX(RI)"
```

Comment: names(df) <- c("Code","LX(VO)","TX(RI)","NX(RI)")

df <- df[,grepl("Code|RI",names(df))]